# Silverlight 4: How can I convert bmp byte array to png byte array?

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, image, bmp

I have a wcf service which returns a bmp in byte[]. However Silverlight's Image control doesnt support displaying bmp's so i need to convert the bmp byte[] to png or jpg byte[]. Is there a library out there which does this conversion? Or any other way of displaying the bmp byte[] on the silverlight client?

Thanks!

**Update1**

In order to achieve the conversion I would have done something like this in .NET

```
private byte[]  ConvertBmpToJpeg(byte[] bmp)
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bmp)))
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();                
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
 }
```

Since System.Drawing is not available in Silverlight, how do I achieve what the code does above in Silverlight?

**Answer**
using the library mentioned by dj kraze below-

```
        ExtendedImage img = new ExtendedImage();
        var bd = new BmpDecoder();
        var je = new JpegEncoder();
        bd.Decode(img, new MemoryStream(bitmapBytes));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        je.Encode(img, ms);

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.SetSource(new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()));
        display_ScreenShot.Source = bi;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an even easier way of doing it.. 
This site may help out a lot

[Image Converting](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/12/saving-images-bmp-png-etc-in-wpf-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Trying this out, I think decoding bmp byte stream to Image and then encoding the Image to Png byte stream can be done with this library. Will update soon!

Comment: I was able to get the conversion using the library