# Load .BMP image in WP7 App

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to load a BMP image in Windows Phone 7 application but when the extension is. bmp the image does not appear. However, the code works with .jpg, .png and .gif.
I'm using the following code snippet:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("Images/test.bmp", UriKind.Relative);
ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(uri);
imageView.Source = img;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as a `png`. Silverlight doesn't support `bmp` out of the box (see [Silverlight 4 BitmapImage - bmp file support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719958/silverlight-4-bitmapimage-bmp-file-support)).

Alternatively, if you really need to do this, you'll need to use a third-party library. The [.net Image Tools Library](http://imagetools.codeplex.com/) has the BMP converters you need. There's some sample code in this question: [Silverlight 4: How can I convert bmp byte array to png byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233154/silverlight-4-how-can-i-convert-bmp-byte-array-to-png-byte-array)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I need to show a bmp... What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly.